# How we can read SharePoint file stream without execute-query?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online

```
 if (clientContext.HasPendingRequest)
    {
      clientContext.ExecuteQueryWithRetry();
      FileInformation fileInformation = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, 
      item.FieldValues["FileRef"].ToString());
using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileInformation.Stream, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
 {
String xml = sr.ReadToEnd();
 }
    }
```

This code is reading stream , but the problem is that in case of 1000 documents executequery will 1000 times . is there any alternative to read multiple streams.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to load multiple files in batch to optimize the frequency requests.

Fake code:

```
var fileList = new List<FileInformation>();
            var requestBatch = 0;
            foreach (var item in items)
            {
                FileInformation fileInformation = File.OpenBinaryDirect(ctx, item.FieldValues["FileRef"].ToString());
                fileList.Add(fileInformation);
                requestBatch++;
                if (requestBatch % 10 == 0)
                {
                    ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry(2);
                }

            }
//to do, get file from fileList
```